# qmlscene replace c++ module

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have a qml import statment that is something like

```
import com.my.namespace.logic
```

and this is from a c++ registered class

```
qmlRegisterType<ApplicationController>("com.my.namespace.logic", 1, 0, "ApplicationController");
```

Now I want to be able to use qmlscene to run this with special testing logic. So I made a folder structure like

```
▾ testingdata/
  ▾ com/
    ▾ my/
      ▾ namespace/
        ApplicationController.qml
        LoginController.qml
        MasterController.qml
        qmldir
```

I made sure that my qmldir's first line was

```
module logic
```

Then tried to run

```
qmlscene -I testingdata main.qml
```

but it will always complain that my namespace isn't registered. Has anyone tried to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is I made another project that includes all the headers and source plus some extended classes so that it could run as a separate executable that doesn't connect to any online services.